# Azure No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to move my api service (written in web api) to azure.
I have openned a website and moved it there.
In the web api I have these attributes:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

On the old website (not azure) all the requests return data, regardless from which domain I am trying to get data.

After I moved the web api to the new website in azure, I started to recieve the next error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

When the web api located on the old website, it works (from localhost, and other kinds of sources).

Is there any configuration to do in the azure portal? or perhaps to change the web.config?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My team and I have created a demo which demonstrates how to build a Web API with an AngularJS front end which requires CORS enabled. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/azure-appservice-samples/ToDoApp/tree/master/src/MultiChannelToDo)

A few things to note from this sample:

- Uses the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors NuGet Package
- Enable CORS in the WebApiConfig.cs in App_Start folder
- Web.config: Remove Handlers: **OPTIONSVerbHandler**, **TRACEVerbHandler**, **WebDAV**
- Web.config: Remove Module: **WebDAVModule**

Answer (score -1):

Please check this document that talks about " Set the Allowed Origins" that might help.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#allowed-origins

Regards,
Shirisha Paderu